# How can I send one agent to another agent in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a reservation object, which I want to send to the car agent so that the car is set with the attributes of the reservation object, when the car arrives. The car will be injected when the arrivaltime is reached. So I tried injecting a car to the car source on the "on exit" section of the delay block of the reservation pipeline and then sending the reservation object to the car statechart with:

```
send(agent, Car);
```

but it says: "Car cannot be resolved to a variable".

Can anyone help how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Understand how keywords work in code sections. The "on exit" code block will have specific keywords that can be used, if you hover over the little lightbulb you can learn about them. See my [blog post](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling) on this.

In your case, however, you have not actually connected a reservation with a car. Your car just appears in the source.

Best read up on agent connections, then connect your reservation to the car agent being created. Hope this helps a little